# Condition check and Put on different tables in one DDB network call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Here are my tables:

Table1

- Id (String, composite PK partition key)
- IdTwo (String, composite PK sort key)

Table2

- IdTwo (String, simple PK partition key)
- Timestamp (Number)

I want to PutItem in Table1 only if IdTwo does not exist in Table2 or the item in Table2 with the same IdTwo has Timestamp less than the current time (can be given as outside input).

The simple approach I know would work is:

1. GetItem on Table2 with ConsistentRead=true. If item exists or its Timestamp < current time, exit early.
2. PutItem on Table1.

However, this is two network calls to DDB. I'd prefer optimizing it, like using TransactWriteItems which is one network call. Is it possible for my use case?

If you want to share code, I'd prefer Go, but any language is fine.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the operation you're looking for is `TransactWriteItems` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html

This is the API operation that lets you do atomic and transactional conditional writing operations. There's two parts to your question, not sure they can be done together—but then they might not need to be.

The first part, insert in table1 if condition is met in table2 is simple enough—you add the item you want in table1 in the `Put` section of the API call, and phrase the existence check for table2 in the `ConditionCheck` section.

You can't do multiple checks right now, so the check to see if the timestamp is lower than current time is another separate operation, also in the `ConditionCheck`. You can't combine them together or do just one because of your rules.

I'd suggest doing a bit of optimistic concurrency here. Try the `TransactWriteItems` with the second `ConditionCheck`, where the write will succeed only if the timestamp is less than current time. This is what should happen in most cases. If the transaction fails, now you need to check if it failed because the timestamp was lower or because the item doesn't yet exist.

If  it doesn't yet exist, then do a `TransactWiteItems` where you populate the timestamp with a `ConditionCheck` to make sure it doesn't exist (another thread might have written it in the meantime) and then retry the first operation.

You basically want to keep retrying the first operation (write with condition check to make sure timestamp is lower) until it succeeds or fails for a good reason. If it fails because the data is uninitialized, initizalize it taking into account race conditions and then try again.